# Registering users in Laravel as Admin

Tags: laravel

My current project is a school management system, and I'm using Laravel 5.6 (it's my first Laravel project). I've been trying to register a user from a small form I have inside the Administrator area of my application.

I've set up the routes for the Admin area (view names are not in English, sorry for that):

```
// Admin
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
  Route::view('/admin', 'profiles.admin.admin_gerencia_cadastro');
  Route::view('/admin/gerencia/cadastro', 'profiles.admin.admin_gerencia_cadastro');
  Route::post('/admin/gerencia/cadastro', 'RegController@store');
  Route::view('/admin/gerencia/relatorios', 'profiles.admin.admin_gerencia_relatorios');
  Route::view('/admin/ped/', 'profiles.admin.admin_ped');
});
```

The post route (third from the top) was supposed to handle registration of users and leads to `RegController` and the following method:

```
  public function store()
     {

         $this->validate(request(), [
           'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
           'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
           'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
         ]);

         $user = User::create(request(['name', 'email', 'password']));

         return redirect()->to('/admin/gerencia/cadastro');
     }
```

It should store the new user data and redirect the Admin back to `/admin/gerencia/cadastro`. However, when the form is submitted data is *not* stored on the database and I'm redirected to the homepage instead. I've tried different things, consulted the documentation, but no success so far.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Edit:

Came here to post the form, as requested below, but I found my own mistake - a rookie one: the form action was wrong. Sorry guys, I'll close the question :)

Comment: Use validator files as the manual recommends for validation. What does dd(request ());  give you I'd you put it as the first thing in the store function?

Answer (score 0):

Is your request reaching in `store()` method?

try to write

```
print_r($_REQUEST);exit;
```

on first line of method. If it's not reaching there, then put below route before all other routes of your route group:

```
Route::post('/admin/gerencia/cadastro', 'RegController@store');
```

check out [this link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#resource-controllers) for better understanding of routing in laravel.

Comment: It returns an empty array when I add it before the routes, but nothing changes when write it on the method. I don't understand why the data is not being passed to the controller.

Comment: Can you post your form here?

Comment: sure, I'll add it to the post above.